# Add current directory to PATH

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

Is there a way to add the current (the one you're currently in) directory to PATH without having to type it manually; for example

```
f:\TEMP\Add directory f:\TEMP to PATH without having to do

set PATH=%PATH%;f:\TEMP;
```

Comment: Are you looking to add a specific directory to `PATH` once so you can use it in the future, or are you looking to add every directory you go to into `PATH` whenever you go into that directory?

Comment: @tchen - I'm looking for a way to add the directory I'm currently inside to PATH, but without having to type its name.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`%CD%` expands to current directory.

So you can use:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%CD%
```

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for. ge0rdi, thank you.

Comment: I get, `bash: fg: %CD%: no such job`.

Comment: @Web_Designer this is for Windows. You can do it in a bash shell (*nix) with `export PATH=".:$PATH" although it is a little bit of a security vulnerability and generally frowned upon.